# ADO.NET Entity Data Model и MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, ado.net, entity

Скачал последний коннектор с сайта mysql.com, подключил к студии, добавил референсы.
В ServerExplorer сервер подключился, соединение работает нормально. Пытаюсь добавить в проект Entity Data Model, получаю такую ошибку:

[image: System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException]

Dataset нормально создается, но хочется работать именно с Entity Data Model, подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень может быть, что ничего не получиться сделать - используемый Вами провайдер несовместим с EF.

Возможно, удастся поработать не со специализированным клиентом MySql, а через ODBC или OleDb.

Comment: Не, MySQL .Net Connector, поддерживает EF.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-entity-framework.html

Comment: Не совместимой оказалась устаревшая БД, из-за чего она не правильно работала с библиотекой.